# What is the reason for this error in my manifest file

Tags: javascript, node.js, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a progressive Web App in Nodejs environment. 
I get a 404 and syntax error in console panel. I am unable to identify exactly whats wrong with my manifest code.

```
service worker registered     (pwa.js:3)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     (manifest.json:1) 

Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.     (manifest.json:1)

caching shell assets     (sw.js:14)
```

My root directory structure:

```
/node_modules/
/public/
        css/
        images/
        home.html
        index.html
        pwa.js
        sw.js

/app.js
manifest.json
package.json
```

This is my manifest.json file

```
{
  "name": "PlayPack",
  "short_name": "PlayPack",
  "start_url": "/public/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#FFE9D2",
  "theme_color": "#FFE1C4",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/public/images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "72x72"
    },
    {
      "src": "/public/images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "/public/images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "/public/images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "144x144"
    },
    {
      "src": "/public/images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "152x152"
    },
    {
      "src": "/public/images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/public/images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "384x384"
    },
    {
      "src": "/public/images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
}
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");    
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');    
const app = express();    
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));        
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");

});
app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/home.html");

 });
```

pwa.js file checks if('serviceWorker' in navigator){ } and registers the service worker . It does nothing else.

I would like to know if its really necessary to specify an index.html file in my Manifest file?

Obviously I have not worked in PWA's before. Please guide me

Comment: can you set `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` at the end of your code and try again ?

Comment: I get Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Comment: is there any reason for  ? which file is missing?

Comment: can you print out what this gives you `__dirname + "/public/home.html"`

Comment: I just noticed there was a missing "/"  in res.sendFile(__dirname + "public/index.html"). So I changed it to "/public/index.html. And then moved app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); to the end of the code in app.js. Now I do not get ENOENT error. However i still get the same manifest file error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your manifest.json file to /public folder since this is where the static files are served from.